# project does not contain a configuration called 'Debug|x64'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, 64-bit, vcbuild

I'm trying to build a C++ project with a build configuration platform of x64.
It's on a new machine running a 64 bit Windows Server 2008.
When I open the build configuration manager in VS, I can't chose or create the x64 platform and the project gets skipped.
When I try to build it with MSBuild I get the error:
VCBLD0004: Project 'MyProject' does not contain a configuration called 'Debug|x64'

Project is built fine on a different machine, but not on the new one, so I guess I missed something in the installation.
Any ideas what to look for?

Comment: Deleting my answer about the x64 compiler, as apprently that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw, Problem was that VS (and with it the x64 compilers and tools) was installed after the SDK.
Had to uninstall and reinstall the SDK, then run a repair on it, then everything works fine.
You can try just the repair as mentioned here:
http://cygon.nuclex.org/2008/04/06/visual-studio-2008-professional-no-x64/

Comment: The above link has changed to http://cygon.nuclex.org/post/2008/04/06/no-x64-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx